# Can I use phone authentication without creating a user on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I know that Firebase has phone authentication. Can I use it without the need to create a user each time? I have already the info in MongoDB, just need Firebase to send the message to the number. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Firebase requires all authentication options to be attached to a user account that it controls.

If all you require is to send a txt message to a number to validate it, you should use some service that will provide just that service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does Google have a service like this?

Comment: I thought that is possible to do as you can do with push notifications, you dont need a user to send, just a FCM token

Comment: No, you need a different service that specifically works with SMS messages.

Comment: What is the best service that I can use?

Comment: @Cipri I don't know which is the best, But Twilio have service as you said.